# Timers in javascript don't want to stop counting sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, clearinterval

I have 3 timers in javascript and I created buttons to control their flow (switch them). However (only!) sometimes they don't want to stop. Where can be the problem? Too much timers? I was testing it on Google Chrome.

So, most important parts of my code:

```
//to insert infos
function addInfo(info){
    $("#info").text(info);
    clearTimeout(window.myTimer);
    window.myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $("#info").text("");
    }, 5000);

    return true;
}

function startHTML(){
    window.TimerHTML = setInterval(function(){
        //ajax
    }, 500);
}

function startView(){
    window.TimerView = setInterval(function(){
        //ajax
    }, 2000);
}

function stop_html(){
    clearInterval(TimerHTML);
    startView();
    addInfo("html->view ");
}

function start_html(){
    clearInterval(TimerView);
    startHTML();
    addInfo("view->html");
}

$(function() { 
    startView();
    start_html();

    //these actions should switch timers
    $("#stop_html").click(function(){
        stop_html();
        return false;
    });

    $("#start_html").click(function(){
        start_html();
        return false;
    });
});
```

EDIT: added html

```html
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-allwidth" id="start_html" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="View->Html">HTML ON</button> 
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-allwidth" id="stop_html" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="HTML->View">HTML OFF</button> 

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:$('#info-container').toggle('slow'); return false;" class="btn btn-primary btn-allwidth" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Infos">Infos<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></a>

 <div id="info-container">
  <div id="info" class="alert alert-success"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML?

Comment: you seem to instantiate two timers via setInterval, why not having two different variables? (because when you stop them, you only have access to the last one instantiated (the one from start_html))

Comment: What do you mean? I have different variables: window.myTimer, window.TimerHTML, and window.TimerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If either of startHTML or startView is executed in succession (i.e. startHTML is executed two times continuously) then you end up creating two intervals.

When you execute

```
window.TimerHTML = setInterval(function(){
    //ajax
}, 500);
```

twice in succession, window.TimerHTML gets a new interval assigned to it. But that does not mean that the previous interval that was assigned to window.TimerHTML prior to this has been cleared. It still goes on but is no longer assigned a variable to be accessed.

You can test it by running these two commands successively

```
window.TimerHTML = setInterval(function(){
    console.log("A");
}, 500);
    window.TimerHTML = setInterval(function(){
    console.log("B");
}, 500);
```

Even if you clear window.TimerHTML you would still see "A" being logged in the console. That is becuase the previous timer never got cleared. And TimerHTML no longer has access to it.

This could be a reason why your timers wouldn't stop.